# 'expected slice, found u8' error when parsing bytes with Kuchiki

Tags: rust, kuchiki

I'm running into a type error when trying to do the following:

```
use kuchiki::parse_html;
use kuchiki::traits::*;

fn main() {
    let data = r#"<!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html>
                      <body>
                          test
                      </body>
                  </html>"#;
    let dom = parse_html()
        .from_utf8()
        .from_iter(data.as_bytes());
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<tendril::fmt::Bytes as tendril::fmt::SliceFormat>::Slice == u8`
  --> src/main.rs:13:10
   |
13 |         .from_iter(data.as_bytes());
   |          ^^^^^^^^^ expected slice, found u8
   |
   = note: expected type `[u8]`
              found type `u8`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<tendril::tendril::Tendril<tendril::fmt::Bytes>>` for `&u8`
```

`data.as_bytes()` returns a reference to a slice of bytes (`&[u8]`), so I'm confused as to where the `found u8` is coming from.  How do I rectify this error?

The docs for the method in question [are here](https://docs.rs/kuchiki/0.7.3/kuchiki/traits/trait.TendrilSink.html#method.from_iter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `read_from()` instead of `from_iter()`, like this:

```
use kuchiki::parse_html;
use kuchiki::traits::*;

fn main() {
    let data = r#"<!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html>
                      <body>
                          test
                      </body>
                  </html>"#;
    let dom = parse_html()
        .from_utf8()
        .read_from(&mut data.as_bytes());
}
```

You got the compile error because `from_iter()` needs an iterator with item type `Tendril`. A Tendril is a kind of string, so the type of `data` would need to be something like `Vec<&[u8]>`, but you have `&[u8]`.

You can also make it work using `from_iter()`, but it's a bit less clear/efficient:

```
use kuchiki::parse_html;
use kuchiki::traits::*;

fn main() {
    let data = r#"<!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html>
                      <body>
                          test
                      </body>
                  </html>"#;
    let dom = parse_html()
        .from_utf8()
        .from_iter(vec![data.as_bytes()]);
}
```